# Comparing files and removing duplicates

Tags: awk, diff, text-formatting

I have two files, test1 and test2. I would like to compare the files and remove any entries in test2 that are already present in test1.

Example:

**test1**

```
[ostrich@post-om1 test]$ cat test1|head
917010023586,UPE,RED 399
917023895388,UPE,RED 499
917023895389,UPE,RED 699
917024120800,UPE,RED 399
917024214387,UPE,RED 399
917027011096,UPE,RED 399
917027120457,UPE,RED 399
917027749420,UPE,RED 399
917030002266,UPE,RED 399
919389105220,UPE,RED 399
```

**test2**

```
[ostrich@post-om1 test]$ cat test2|head
917310106487
919839063308
917081106519
919389105220
919336429543
917081102867
919919804079
919936432138
919455329240
919839601519
```

**Desired output**

```
[ostrich@post-om1 test]$ cat test1
917010023586,UPE,RED 399
917023895388,UPE,RED 499
917023895389,UPE,RED 699
917024120800,UPE,RED 399
917024214387,UPE,RED 399
917027011096,UPE,RED 399
917027120457,UPE,RED 399
917027749420,UPE,RED 399
917030002266,UPE,RED 399
```

Comment: show what you've tried... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739213/create-diff-between-two-files-based-on-specific-column for similar question

Comment: This question "title" is an impudence.

Comment: "remove any entries in test2 that are already present in test1" – Your example output doesn't remove anything from `test2`; it removes lines from `test1`...

Answer (score 2):

I need nine more characters...

```
grep -vFf test2 test1
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved above result by below command and it worked fine

---

```
awk -F ","  'NR==FNR {a[$1];next}!($1 in a) {print $0}' test2 test1
```

---